# Отсечение строк по регулярному выражению с помощью GREP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian

Всем привет, имеются следующий лог. Задача: вывести строки в виде GET и далее до конца строки. То есть по маске GET*. Формат лога:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная команда выводит только "GET":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в этом же логе таким же методом удалось отсечь IP адреса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

объясните, пожалуйста, данное поведение, весь Гугл уже перерыл

Comment: `grep -o -E 'GET.*'`

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо! А зачем нужна точка перед *?

Comment: `.` в регулярных выражениях  означает "любой символ". `*` говорит, что предыдущее соответствие (в данном случае "любой символ") может отсутствовать либо повториться неограниченное количество раз. Т.е. в регулярных выражениях комбинация `.*` соответствует любому тексту, включая пустую строку. И `GET.*` соответствует тексту начинающемуся со слова GET и до конца строки.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. До конца думал, что * можно использовать отдельно как "любой символ от 0 и до бесконечности раз".

Comment: Когда вы написали `GET*` (без точки), это выражение соответствовало бы строкам `GE` (потому что `T*`, т.е. символ T не обязателен), а также `GET`, `GETT`, `GETTTTTTTT` и так далее (потому что `T*`, т.е. символ T может повторяться сколько угодно раз).

Answer (score 0):

`grep -E "(^GET.*)"` - выведет все от GET и до конца.

Если нужно то, что в скобках, то можно так:

`grep -oP '(?s)(?<=00].").*?(?=")'` - данное выржение сделает выборку начиная с символов `00] "`, однако при этом их обрежет, и до символа `"` (его тоже обрежет).

Таким образом, будет получена строка между `""`.